# Don't send Axios request when user selects a result

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

I'm using v-autocomplete  from vuetify.js to retrieve a list of values from API Server.

It works fine and my list of values is not empty.

But my problem is when I select the correct value from this list. My script sends another request to server to retrieve another autocomplete list.

Do you have any idea to avoid to send request when a result is selected by the user ? Or to send request only when a key is down ?

My component :

```
   <template>
  <div>
    <v-autocomplete
      v-model="selectValeur"
      :loading="loading"
      :search-input.sync="search"
      :items="resultatsAutocomplete"
      class="mb-4"
      hide-no-data
      hide-details
      :label="recherche.label"
    ></v-autocomplete>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    recherche: {
      type: Object,
      default: null,
    },
  },
  data: () => ({
    selectValeur: null,
    loading: false,
    search: null,
    resultatsAutocomplete: [],
  }),
  watch: {
    selectValeur(oldval, val) {
      console.log(oldval)
      console.log(val)
    },
    search(val) {
      val && val !== this.selectValeur && this.fetchEntriesDebounced(val)
      console.log(val)
      if (!val) {
        this.resultatsAutocomplete = []
      }
    },
  },
  methods: {
    fetchEntriesDebounced(val) {
      // cancel pending call
      clearTimeout(this._timerId)

      // delay new call 500ms
      this._timerId = setTimeout(() => {
        this.querySelections(val)
      }, 500)
    },
    async querySelections(v) {
      if (v.length > 1) {
        this.loading = true
        try {
          const result = await this.$axios.$get(
            'myapi/myurl',
            {
              params: {
                racine: v,
              },
            }
          )
          this.resultatsAutocomplete = result
          console.log(this.resultatsAutocomplete)
          this.loading = false
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err)
          this.loading = false
        }
      } else {
        this.resultatsAutocomplete = []
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

`selectValeur` would no longer be `null` if the user has selected a value, so you could update `search()` to return if `selectValeur` is truthy:

```js
export default {
  watch: {
    search(val) {
      if (this.selectValeur) {
        // value already selected
        return
      }

      //...
    }
  }
}
```

Or you could use [`vm.$watch`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch) on the `search` property to be able to stop the watcher when `selectValeur` is set:

```js
export default {
  mounted() {
    this._unwatchSearch = this.$watch('search', val => {
      val && val !== this.selectValeur && this.fetchEntriesDebounced(val)
      if (!val) {
        this.resultatsAutocomplete = []
      }
    })
  },
  watch: {
    selectValeur(val) {
      if (val && this._unwatchSearch) {
        this._unwatchSearch()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem.
I used the @keyup event to send the axios request and I deleted the watcher on search.
So, the API request are only sent when I press a key.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-autocomplete
      v-model="selectValeur"
      :loading="loading"
      :items="resultatsAutocomplete"
      :search-input.sync="search"
      class="mb-4"
      hide-no-data
      hide-details
      :label="recherche.label"
      @keyup="keyupSearch"
    ></v-autocomplete>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    recherche: {
      type: Object,
      default: null,
    },
  },
  data: () => ({
    selectValeur: null,
    loading: false,
    resultatsAutocomplete: [],
    search: '',
  }),
  methods: {
    keyupSearch(val) {
      val &&
        val !== this.selectValeur &&
        this.fetchEntriesDebounced(this.search)
      if (!val) {
        this.resultatsAutocomplete = []
      }
    },
    fetchEntriesDebounced(val) {
      // cancel pending call
      clearTimeout(this._timerId)
      // delay new call 500ms
      this._timerId = setTimeout(() => {
        this.querySelections(val)
      }, 500)
    },
    async querySelections(v) {
      if (v.length > 1) {
        this.loading = true
        try {
          const result = await this.$axios.$get(
            'my-api/my-url',
            {
              params: {
                sid: this.$route.params.sid,
                service: this.$route.params.service,
                type: this.recherche.mode,
                racine: v,
              },
            }
          )
          this.resultatsAutocomplete = result
          console.log(this.resultatsAutocomplete)
          this.loading = false
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err)
          this.loading = false
        }
      } else {
        this.resultatsAutocomplete = []
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```